# ListView insertitem template

Tags: asp.net

I have one listview that compiles layout template,  item template and insert item template. Rest is working fine except insert item template hide/show functionality. I have a requirement to hide or show the insert item template, what i have tried till now is..i took one asp button and wrote the following line on click event.

```
lvwCustomers.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None
```

It does nothing on the first click but it disables the insert item template on the second click and after that my submit button gives object reference exception.

Any Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.InsertItem.Visible = false;      
}
```